# Combining elements in a list - OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Is it possible to create a list by combing elements of a list rather than creating a list of lists?

Example:

```
List.combine ["A";"B"] ["C";"D"];;
```

I get:

```
[("A", "C"); ("B", "D")]
```

Is it possible to generate `["A";"B";"C";"D"]` ?

Comment: You can use: List.concat (for example: List.concat [l1; l2]; where l1=[A;B] and l2 = [C;D] or List.append l1 l2

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the `@` operator or `List.append` is what you want.

Example with the `@` operator:

```
# let x = 4::5::[];;
val x : int list = [4; 5]
# let y = 5::6::[];;
val y : int list = [5; 6]
# let z = x@y;;     
val z : int list = [4; 5; 5; 6]
```